# Datagrid binding asynchronous wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid

everyone. I'm using WPF and trying to fill datagrid asynchronous, so it won't lock the UI.
I'm loading the data from DB in asynchronous way, But if i have many record so the UI is locked until it finish fill the Datagrid. I tried almost everything and nothing is working.

this is my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgOrgAtts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="195,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" RenderTransformOrigin="0.051,-0.272" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsEnabled="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" CanUserResize="False" Width="30" >
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Checked="all_Checked" Unchecked="all_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <EventSetter Handler="OrgAtt_Checked" Event="ToggleButton.Checked"/>
                                <EventSetter Handler="OrgAtt_Unchecked" Event="ToggleButton.Unchecked"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AttName, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="סוג קבוצת שיוך" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AttText, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="שם קבוצת שיוך" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrgAttId, Mode=OneWay,  IsAsync=True}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="מספר" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And this is how i'm bind the list to the datagrid:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Source = orgAtt;
                binding.IsAsync = true;
                dgOrgAtts.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

its working, but lock the UI.
I would like to have your help.

Comment: You tell us that you have tried a lot of things. Can you be more specific? What _exactly_ have you tried?

Comment: don't disable row virtualization. that cause DataGrid to create *a lot* of rows - which is slow

Comment: @ASh Thank you!
Now from  40 seconds it reduced to 1 sec!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only option is to have to write every item one by one in an asynchronous Task into your data collection (must be observable). If you try to render (because, as far as I can tell from experience, the problem is the rendering, not the assignment) a lot of data at once it will cause the UI to freeze.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _tokens.Add(token);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (token.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Collection.Add(item));
                RaisePropertyChanged("Collection");
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            if (token.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in list)
                        Collection.Remove(item);
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Collection");
                });

            _tokens.Remove(token);
        }, token.Token);
```

Working fine using MVVM :)

Answer (score -1):

How many data rows are you trying to display in a grid that is putting such a load onto the system?

A better way would be to separate out the data loading from the U.I. display. Bind the DataGrid's ItemSource to an ObservableCollection of items. Fetch the data from the database, in an asynchronous manner, either using direct database access or some kind of ORM, and then add those items to the observable collection.